# Dynamically fetch all the related lists for an Object (for eg. Account)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am working on a project which requires dynamically fetch related child items for a particular record  - I only need those related child objects for which the current record has related lists in the page layout or the current user profile has access to this.

Comment: please share the code which you have for this moment. It'll be a start point for further discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use with something like this function to get related objects and after use dynamic SOSL query

```
 public static map<string,string> getRelatedObjects(string masterObjectName){
        map<string,string> relatedObjectsMap = new map<string,string>();
        list<Schema.Childrelationship> relatedObjectsList = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(masterObjectName).getdescribe().getChildRelationships();
        for (Schema.Childrelationship  relatedObject : relatedObjectsList) {
             if(relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isUpdateable()
                    && 
                    relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()!=null
                    && 
                    !relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isCustomSetting()
                    &&
                    relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isCreateable()
                )
                relatedObjectsMap.put(relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName(),relatedObject.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getLabel());
       }
        return relatedObjectsMap;
    }
```